# Convert Numpy array into a sine wave signal for Fourier analysis

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, fft

I have a long tabular data, simple peak amplitude measurement with respect to time, i.e 1D array index of interval 1 minute.

```
>>> a = np.array([5, 7, -6, 9, 0, 1, 15, -2, 8]) 
#array is of length of many thousands readings taken on interval of 1 minute. 
#The index represents 1-minute interval.
```

How can I convert this NumPy array into a "signal" that I can use to perform FFT on it, either in NumPy `numpy.fft` or any other library?

Comment: Your array `a` is already ideal as a signal.

Comment: What do you think is wrong with your signal that it cannot be analysed using FFT? Sometimes some pre-processing steps are mandatory (e.g. windowing of the signal to fight circular nature of the Fourier Transform) but in general, any array of numbers (real or even complex) can be an input of Fourier Transform.

Comment: I thought I must process this array since it is only peak amplitude value, and the signal needs to be sign wave with multiple values in single wave to define the shape.

Comment: Are you referring to aliasing issues? If so, you indeed need to consider the sampling frequency relative to the data frequency (see [Nyquist frequency](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Nyquist_frequency)). But if you don't know the signal ahead of time and already have the data then it is too late to change anything. If you knew the data frequency and wanted to resample what you have so that it met the requirements to avoid antialiasing, well, then you wouldn't be doing FFT because you would already know the result.

Comment: I tried using the array as it is. I am getting meaningless outcomes. I do not know what is going wrong here. I am posting a new question with code and graphs.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform FFT using  [np.fft.fft](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft.html) :

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([5, 7, -6, 9, 0, 1, 15, -2, 8]) 

a_fft = np.fft.fft(a)
```

Output:

```
array([ 37.         +0.j        ,   2.1617886 +10.12019119j,
         3.88830807 -3.48605171j,  25.         -1.73205081j,
       -27.05009668 +1.98221437j, -27.05009668 -1.98221437j,
        25.         +1.73205081j,   3.88830807 +3.48605171j,
         2.1617886 -10.12019119j])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a time array with 1-minute intervals and then turn it into a time series since your data shows peak amplitudes at 1-minute intervals. first a time series with evenly spaced time interval should be created.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([5, 7, -6, 9, 0, 1, 15, -2, 8])

# Sample rate (1 sample per minute)
sample_rate = 1  # samples per minute

# a time array
time = np.arange(0, len(a)) / sample_rate  
# Your data 'a', and the appropriate time values are in 'time'.  

# using numpy.fft library 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Perform FFT on the data
fft_result = np.fft.fft(a)

# Calculate the frequency axis
frequencies = np.fft.fftfreq(len(a), d=1/sample_rate)

# Plot the FFT result
plt.plot(frequencies, np.abs(fft_result))
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.title('FFT Result')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```